# Understanding Typescript's views on inheritance

Tags: programming-languages, programming-practices, inheritance, typescript

I have been struggling to understand the reasons why typescript developers choose the way they implemented inheritance.

What I would expect from any language supporting inheritance is these order of work:

1. The derived class initialized properties are initialized
2. The base class initialized properties are initialized
3. The base class constructor runs
4. The derived class constructor runs

What apparently happens:

1. The base class initialized properties are initialized
2. The base class constructor runs
3. The derived class initialized properties are initialized
4. The derived class constructor runs

I don't yet understand what kinds of benefits come from implementing this kind of inheritance

My question boiling down to this:

What kinds of projects makes this implementation of inheritance perfect for?

EDIT: relevant link to discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1617

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: I don't understand the close vote, it looks both like a legitimate and even interesting question to me.  ...*maybe* the reason is related to some JavaScript constraints / compatibility issues.

Comment: @gnat Should I rephrase to "Is there a reason why the second option set is a bad one?" like in this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157110/new-license-similar-to-agpl-but-only-for-javascript-and-css

Comment: @user108589: your *EDIT* github link pretty much summarizes the reasoning behind it. There you have your answer.

Comment: @dagnelies I only see arguments in favor of the first list not the second

Comment: @dagnelies: the question asks for a list of projects (or more precisely, for a list of kinds of projects). List questions are off-topic. The interestingness of the question is irrelevant. There are lots of things that are of interest, but not on-topic.

Comment: This can be argued both ways. TypeScript's initialization protocol is enjoyably simple and is also used by C++: property initialization is part of the ctor, and the base class is fully initialized before the subclass. C++ also forbids virtual calls in the ctor. The alternatives introduce more complexity: the base class now needs to know whether a property was already initialized. I have never seen a case where overriding a property was a good and obvious design, except for certain idioms in C#/Java. Generally: if the initial value isn't known during design, it should be assigned by the ctor.

Comment: It is more than simply following the protocol of another language. The order of initialization ensures that pre-conditions and invariants in the base class are satisfied before the derived class begins execution. This is important for proving correctness.